Rectangle has a black background
Rectangle has a black background when pdf is set on a unit of inches. I want it just blank rectangle with a thin black outline, can't change it into a different unit because most of my work depends on inches unit. When it is created in a pdf, it turns into a box overlapped in black background.
const pdf = new jsPDF({
  unit: 'in',  // Set the unit to inches
  format: 'letter' // 'letter' format is 8.5 x 11 inches
});
const x = 1;   
const y = 1;  
const width = 4;  
const height = 2; 
pdf.setFillColor(0, 0, 0); 
pdf.rect(x, y, width, height);


You call setFillColor before drawing the rectangle. If you want to draw just an outline of the rectangle without any fill color, you should use the rect method with the draw parameter set to S (for stroke only):
I could not get your version of jsPDF to work, an older one did (but not here at SO, due to sandbox issues)
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const pdf = new jsPDF({
    unit: 'in', // Set the unit to inches
    format: 'letter' // 'letter' format is 8.5 x 11 inches
  });
  const x = 1;
  const y = 1;
  const width = 4;
  const height = 2;
  pdf.setDrawColor(0, 0, 0); // Set the color for the rectangle outline (black)
  pdf.rect(x, y, width, height, 'S'); // Draw the rectangle with only the outline ('S' stands for Stroke)
  window.open(pdf.output('bloburl'))
});

<!--script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.debug.js"></script>


So.. that's what I've got using script below

You need to add:
pdf.setLineWidth(0.02)
pdf.setFillColor(0, 0, 0) 

to set the line width for the rectangle and to set the border color.
In the end of pdf.rect you need to add 'S' as well so it will draw only border:
pdf.rect(x, y, width, height, "S")


It is always worth using online demo for testing so take the lines example we can experiment. https://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/index.html#
Here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yjrgL5vw/2/ to show old and new (similar code is at end of answer since js.PDF snippets don't seem to work in SO).

Your output result in a PDF is drawn as 14.4 points so unclear why that is the default, it is an odd line thickness (0.2"). Normally it would be 1 w
4 0 obj
<<
/Length 55
>>
stream
14.4018000000000015 w
0 G
0. g
72. 720. 288. -144. re
S
endstream
endobj

When units are "in" then line units are 1" wide (red) and thus the normal PDF default of 1 (overstrike in black) will be 1/72.
Thus all you need is another variable to define current line width. (Inside a PDF that is usually w)
Here your rectangle is not 1 'in' wide borders but 1/72" (a more normal PDF thickness)
pdf.setLineWidth (1/72) for 2 points wide use (1/36) etc.


Oddly it still uses default 14.4 but then corrects/forces that to 1. w (between the 0 G and 0. g) before the re[ctangle] !
4 0 obj
<<
/Length 60
>>
stream
14.4018000000000015 w
0 G
1. w
0. g
72. 720. 288. -144. re
S

P.S note that you do not need to add S that is the default stroking state in js.PDF.
    jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;

    function generatePDF() {
      var doc = new jsPDF({
        unit: "in", // Set the unit to inches
        format: "letter" // 'letter' format is 8.5 x 11 inches
      });
      var w = 1 / 72;
      var x = 1;
      var y = 1;
      var width = 4;
      var height = 2;

      doc.setFillColor(0, 0, 0);
      doc.rect(x, y, width, height);

      doc.setLineWidth(w);
      doc.setDrawColor(0, 0, 0);
      doc.rect(x, y + 3, width, height);

      doc.save("rectangles.pdf");
    }

